# Помогите загрузить данные из XML в Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid, datagridview

Хочу чтобы все узлы вывелись автоматом, без перечисления вручную.
Помогите исправить код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace my_xml_gridview_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument XmlDocument = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

                dataGridView1.DataSource = XmlDocument;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = "Offer";

                MessageBox.Show("Файл загружен");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog>
<shop>
<currencies><currency id="RUR" rate="1" plus="0"/></currencies>
<categories>
<category id="899981" sort_order="0">Смартфоны</category>
</categories>
<offers>
<offer available="true" type="vendor.model" id="89096"><currencyId>RUB</currencyId><delivery>true</delivery><description>Камера - 5 Мпикс</description><local_delivery_cost>0</local_delivery_cost><manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty><model>Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360H Grey</model><modified_time>1434431028</modified_time><name>Смартфон Samsung</name><param name="Глубина">0.8, см</param><param name="Ширина">6.8, см</param><param name="Дисплей">4,5"</param><param name="Стандарт">GSM, 3G</param><param name="Тип дисплея">TFT</param><param name="Камера">5 Мпикс</param><param name="Оперативная память">1Гб</param><param name="Операционная система">Android</param><param name="Карта памяти">microSD (TransFlash) до 64Гб</param><param name="Тип процессора">четырехъядерный</param><param name="Количество цветов">16 млн. цветов</param><param name="Цвет">серый</param><param name="Запись видео">30 кадров/сек.</param><param name="Маx разрешение при видео">1280x720</param><param name="Время в режиме разговора">до 10 часов</param><param name="Wi-Fi">802.11 b/g/n</param><param name="Частота">1,2 ГГц</param><param name="Разрешение дисплея">480х800</param><param name="Время воспроизведения музыки">до 40 часов</param><param name="GPS">есть</param><param name="Камера для видеоконференций">2 Мпикс</param><param name="Высота">13.1, см</param><param name="Вес">133 г</param><param name="Емкость аккумулятора">2000 мАч</param><pickup>true</pickup><picture>http://static.ru/111.jpg</picture><price>7999.00</price><store>true</store><typePrefix>Смартфон</typePrefix><url>https://site.ru/catalog</url><vendor>Samsung</vendor><vendorCode>SM-G360HHADSER</vendorCode></offer><categoryId>899981</categoryId>
</offers></shop></yml_catalog>
```

Код программы не создан мною, а надерган со всяких сайтов и похоже он в корне неправильный. Сплошные ошибки. Помогите исправить. Вот ошибка на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ругается на эту строку
dataGridView1.DataMember = "offer"; писал и offers - ругается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начните с замены `catch(Exception){MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");}` на `catch(Exception e){MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());}`.

Comment: ругается на E (тут (Exception e)). невозможно объявить локальную переменную с именем е. Согласен без вывода любых сообщений. Помогите

Comment: @Андрей поменяйте на ex

Comment: Вы язык хоть немного знаете вообще? `catch(Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());}`

Comment: Помогите вытащить хоть 1 узел model - ничего не получается. <model>Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360H Grey</model> XML файл прикрепил выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если хочется автоматом, то вот:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
```

Чтобы показать не все колонки, а только отдельные, есть два способа.

1. Скрыть ненужные колонки (при этом в DataGridView загружены все):

   ```
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
       if (column.Name != "model" && column.Name != "url")
           column.Visible = false;
   ```

   Этот код пишем уже после привязки данных.
2. Отключить в DataGridView автогенерацию колонок:

   ```
   AutoGenerateColumns = false
   ```

   Добавить в DataGridView только нужные колонки и привязать их к нужным элементам:

   ```
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("model", "Model");
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("url", "Url");
   dataGridView1.Columns["model"].DataPropertyName = "model";
   dataGridView1.Columns["url"].DataPropertyName = "url";
   ```

   Этот код пишем перед привязкой данных.

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо.Подскажите, как вывести 2-3 узла из <offer>? Например <model> и <url>

Comment: @Андрей: Если ответ помог вам, поставьте зелёную галочку. Если у вас есть новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, а не тут.

Comment: Помогите прикрутить dialogbox для выбора файла и передачи управления в dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml"); а то как лох файлы в коде пишу и что не надо комментирую )) Есть код dialoga и dataset но не знаю как передать управление OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
               this.dataGridView1.DataSource = File.ReadAllText(fileDialog.FileName);
            }